# Как хранить сообщения в БД

Tags: javascript, json

Делаю интернет магазин и чат для общения с продавцом.
в чате могут быть только два человек, продавец и человек, который покупает товар этого самого продавца.

> Как хранить их переписку в БД?

Я сначала хотел использовать JSON

```js
    let mesaages = {
      seller: 'Что желаете купить сударь?',
      buyer: 'Колбасу сервелат, пожалуйста',
      seller: 'А магазин вам на что?'
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(mesaages));
```

Но потом вдруг оказалось, что Поля с одинаковыми индексами перезаписываются (что в принципе логично)
Ну а вариант с хранением сообщений в колонках sellerMes и buyerMes мне кажется неудобным, тк нужно будет дописывать туда время, потом его оттуда доставать, сравнивать со временем других сообщений.

Хотелось бы вариант с хранением как в JSON только, чтобы поля, естественно, не перезаписывались

Сейчас у меня такая структура таблицы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тип такая таблица?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очевидно, ответ зависит от того, о какой БД речь

Comment: Всм о какой? mySql)

Comment: Тогда просто сделать колонки date, sender, message да и всё

Comment: ну а как их между собой связывать?

Comment: Вы в вопросе ничего ни про какое связывание не писали. О каком связывании речь?

Comment: ну есть колонки date, sender, message. В date лежат значения 1,3,5,6 (упростил данные до цифр, а не дат), как определить какая дата к какому сообщению относятся?

Comment: date, sender и message неразрывно объединены в пределах одной строки таблицы, такое связывание является неизбежным следствием табличной структуры БД со строками и колонками. По-видимому, вам нужно изучить основы mysql, раз вы такой элементарной вещи не знаете

Comment: Вы на верное не поняли. У меня есть таблица chats в ней строки с чатами. cм картинку я добавил в вопросе

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104936/discussion-between---and-andreymal).

Comment: Нужно создать вторую таблицу chat_messages с колонками chatId, date, sender и message. Пихать всё в одну таблицу - неправильно.

Comment: Те нужно под каждую переписку создавать новую таблицу? Как по мне это как-то не цивильно) Будет же очень много таблиц, что очень и очень неудобно

Comment: Зачем под каждую? Разные переписки будут отличаться друг от друга по chatId, следовательно одной таблицы достаточно для хранения всех переписок. Я вам ещё раз рекомендую изучить основы sql, это элементарные вещи.

Comment: Типа такая таблица? в вопрос добавил картинку

Comment: Типа такая. sender можно было бы упростить до цифры 0/1, всё равно больше двух значений не бывает